# How to let typescript return correct type based on parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript

i'm having a code example like this

```
interface BaseQuestionType {
  label?: string
}
export type RadioQuestionType = BaseQuestionType & {
  radio: boolean
}
export type TextQuestionType = BaseQuestionType & {
  text: string
}

function test(c: boolean): (RadioQuestionType | TextQuestionType){

  if (c) {
    return {
      radio: true
    }
  } else {
    return {
      text: '11'
    }
  }
}
```

So you can see i have a function `test(c:boolean)` that takes in a boolean and give the corresponding return object.

The problem is when i use this function, it has error

```
let a = test(true).radio;
```

Typescript told me this error in this line:

```
Property 'radio' does not exist on type 'RadioQuestionType | TextQuestionType'.
  Property 'radio' does not exist on type 'TextQuestionType'.(2339)
```

As you see, according to the logic `( c is true)`, this line of code is correct, how can i tell typescript this? Or is there any other way to implement this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [overload your function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to get the desired behaviour like this:

```ts
function test(c: true):RadioQuestionType;
function test(c: false):TextQuestionType;
function test(c: boolean): (RadioQuestionType | TextQuestionType){
```

[TSPlayground Link](https://tsplay.dev/Gm3p3W)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Nishant's answer, but using [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html):

```
function test<T extends boolean>(c: T): T extends true ? RadioQuestionType : TextQuestionType;
function test(c: boolean): (RadioQuestionType | TextQuestionType){
   ...
}

let a = test(true).radio;
```